# AngularJS Dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand how to manipulate DOM like with JQuery in controller file:

1. select the divs on criteria
2. organize the selected divs

With Jquery : `$('selector)` + manipulate them

Sorry if this question is too general, I don't have an example code to show.

Comment: here look at this it should help [How to think in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: directives are the right place where your DOM manipulation should be placed.

Comment: This all depends. What are you going to do with it later? If you would show example in jQuery I could show how the same things works in angular.

Comment: you do not manipulate DOM directly in Angular. you write directives and use them in such a way that Angular manipulates DOM for you depending on the values in the scopes. Please see the linked post.

Comment: ok thanks for your comments and your links